# Cannot find module "async" Error

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I created a package.json file which contains the following data:
[image]

After that used the following command:

```
    npm install
```

After that my file directory looks like that:

[image]

As you can see "Async" has been installed. But still keep getting this error:

[image]

**Can anyone help??**

**Edited:** Overall view of the Directory

[image]

Comment: I can't see the `async` module inside the `node_modules` folder. What I see is that your main folder `task-management` has a different name from the one you gave to your package in the `package.json` file. Are you sure you're in the same directory?

Comment: @RodrigoMedeiros Apologies I have corrected my mistake. Please see the question. I am still getting the same error but you can see the Async in the node_module list.

Answer (score 2):

Erm, I might be crazy but I don't see async installed in the screenshot.
Try to install it manually via `npm install async`.

Comment: Apologies I have corrected my mistake. Please see the question. I am still getting the same error but you can see the Async in the node_module list.

Answer (score 1):

You can try doing:

```
npm install async
```

instead of:

```
npm install -g async
```

This might help you.

Answer (score 0):

In my case npm install async was still throwing an error so I have done following:

```
1. brew uninstall --force node  (it deletes all node versions you have on computer)

2. brew doctor 

3. brew prune

4. brew install node

5. npm install async
```

Answer (score 0):

For those who are silly just like me, I did

```js
npm install aysnc
```

instead of

```js
npm install async
```

Please mind the spelling